# Swift - dismissing view controller from within a completion block

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, uiviewcontroller, closures

Simple question. If I'm within a completion block - for example facebook login using firebase ... and the login has succeeded. If I want to dismiss the current view controller (login viewcontroller) from within the completion block , do I need to get back to main queue to do this. I'm assuming the login completion block is being done on a background thread and any change to UI (ie dismissing the current view controller) should be done on the main thread ... what's best practice here ... or am I missing something?

```
@IBAction func facebookLoginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    //
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://XXXX.firebaseio.com")
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {
            //successfully logged in
            //get facbook access token
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            //use access token to authenticate with firebase
            ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
                withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    } else {
                        //authData contains
                        print("Logged in! \(authData)")

                        //pop loginvc back to uservc - DO I NEED TO GET MAIN THREAD HERE BEFORE DISMISSING VIEW CONTROLLER
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Same issue as my answer about performSegue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292600/swift-performseguewithidentifier-not-working/32292706#32292706

Comment: You have to do it on the main thread.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you should "pop" back to the main thread to do this. Its pretty simple, just wrap

`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` like this...

**Swift 2.x**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Swift 3 4 & 5:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: not working if called from DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

Comment: You need to make UI updates on the main thread. Don't call this from a background thread

Comment: but I am using DispatchQueue.main.async though

Comment: I don't understand, can you open a question add your code and share the link please and i'll look at it