# Whose view is not in the window hierarchy dispatch_async

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I already checked out a few answers, but I have a different code that I have not seen here with this problem:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

The problem encounters when I switched from VC1 to VC2. This is my code I used:

```
func ToVC2() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        [unowned self] in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToVC2", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Then I have some logic in the prepareforsegue, but I don't think thats the problem here, or is it? If so I will post the code swell. Any help here is welcome!

Comment: What is your question? What do you exactly want to ask?

Comment: How I remove the warning message by changing the code. I am obviously doing something wrong with this message popping up every second in my debug session.

Comment: Why are you using dispatch_async? Are you calling this function inside a closure? Is there any other code you're executing after segue?

Comment: I got it from the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292600/swift-performseguewithidentifier-not-working , the function stand on its own, and I am just executing some easy code after the segue, I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Can you share your code? I don't see any reason yet why you see that warning.

Comment: from what part is **toVC2 method** being executed?