# How to initialize a nested Node.js Schema with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, node.js, mongodb

I am new to Node.js and back-end development generally. I've already set up my server and mongoDB and connected them with my iOS app, so basically I have a userSchema and a postSchema in Node.js, a corresponding User and Post class in Objective-c. How can I initialise these two classes with the attributes I set up in Node.js?

Here is the userSchema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : String,
    password : String
});
```

and the postSchema:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name        : String,
    image       : String,
    description : String,
    comments    : [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }],
    author      : {
        id : {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});
```

In Xcode, I initialize the Post class like this (don't know if this is correct...but it's working):

```
@implementation Post

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        super.objectId = [dic objectForKey:@"_id"];
        _name          = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        _imgURL        = [dic objectForKey:@"image"];
        _caption       = [dic objectForKey:@"description"];
        _comments      = [dic objectForKey:@"comments"];
        _author        = [dic objectForKey:@"author"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In ViewController:

```
static NSString * const kMyAppBaseURLString = @"http://localhost:4000/";

@interface PostDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation PostDetailViewController

- (void)loadData
{
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[kMyAppBaseURLString
       stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"posts/%@", postId]]];

    //HTTP GET Request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
    [request addValue:@"posts/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        if (error == nil)
        {
            post = [[Post alloc]initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL]];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

I want to access the user's username by just `post.author.username`. How do I initialize the `User` class? Also, am I using the correct way to create the Post class? I am quite new to server side programming. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON objects nest in the natural manner. `_author` needs to be constructed recursively, not assigned to the unparsed JSON dictionary. So it should be a typed, stored property (as `User *`) in the definition of `Post`, and would be built exactly like you built the `Post` object itself:

```
_author = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary: [dic objectForKey: @"author"]];
```

And of course you have to write the `User` class similarly to `Post`, with an explicit parsing constructor.

While I'm looking at your code, please see this important issue about respecting the main thread for UI manipulation. Data tasks do *not* execute their callbacks on `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`.

[Swift performSegueWithIdentifier not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292600/swift-performseguewithidentifier-not-working/32292706#32292706)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution works perfectly, and makes my question looks indeed a bit silly...I do need more practice on the basic principles of programming. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Think nothing of it. Well posed question and well above the truly silly posts.