# move to next view controller programmatically

Tags: swift, uibutton

I wonder how to create a function that move to the login page after click login button, with code/programmatic way.

There is my code:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(20, 640, 175, 75))
        loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255, green: 215, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
        loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        loginButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "StarJediSpecialEdition", size: 30)
        loginButton.addTarget(self,
                              action: #selector(ViewController.tapActionButton),
                              forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func tapActionButton(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button is working")
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably looking for performseguewithidentifier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292600/swift-performseguewithidentifier-not-working

Comment: If he Is a beginner, he is preferably looking for self.presentViewController, because segues required extra information and learning about storyboards and how all that works with segues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are multiple ways how you **create** your login page UIViewController:

1. From xib, for example, you can inherit your controller from this class:

```
class XibLoadedVC: UIViewController {
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
        required init() {
            print("init \(type(of: self))")
            let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
            super.init(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        }
    }
```

or just

```
let controller = LoginPageViewController(nibName: "LoginPageViewController", bundle: nil)
```

2. From storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let loginPage = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginPageViewController") as! LoginPageViewController
```

There are multiple ways to **show** controller depending on how you are create it:

1. You can just present controller with:

```
func tapActionButton(sender: UIButton!) {
    let loginPage = LoginPageViewController()
    self.present(loginPage, animated: true)
}
```

2. Programmatically push using navigationController:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(loginPage, animated: true)
```

Requires UINavigationController to work. As you can’t be sure, is your controller inside navigation controller stack or not, there is  optional `navigationController?` to not crush the app :)

3. Storyboard and Segues:

Create segue between your ViewController and LoginPageViewController. 
Give your segue an identifier and also presentation style. For this case it will be `Show` [image: Example]

Now in your ViewController override below method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier"
       let loginPage = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginPageViewController
   }
}
```

On loginButton tap action:

```
func tapActionButton(sender: UIButton!) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

And you are done.

P.S.
Also, there is modern SwiftUI way to do all that, you can look into tutorials and official documentation.

Comment: your answer is actually very detailed, but I am a beginner, so would you tell me please where should i put the code as there is always an error telling me that the name of the view controller I want to present next is undeclared. Thankyou!

Comment: The code should be put in LoginViewController. And from the error I think you haven't declared your next viewController.

Comment: When should i go with any option mentioned above?

Comment: Both ways are totally valid and give you the same result, It's developers choice which one to follow.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create an instance of the next view controller and then either present or push that view controller

To present modally:

```
self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or to push:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

all that stuff with segues apply to storyboards

Cheers!